# Implementing Multi-Tenant Architecture in Django with Shared and Unique Models

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I am working on a large, multi-tenant Django project primarily utilizing Django's ORM capabilities. The project involves a PostgreSQL database where each schema represents a different tenant. Django commands are used to insert data into the db, import data from the db and perform some calculation and then send it back to the db, and delete certain data from the database. In each schema, several tables and views are designated for Business Intelligence (BI) tools.

Many of my Django models are shared across tenants (in structure, not data), but each tenant should also have unique models, which is where my problem stems from. I want to be able to implement unique models per tenant that can have foreign keys to the common models of that tenant. Implementing these unique tenant models in Django has proven to be difficult and I am aware that this is an unconventional use case for Django.

I would like to keep data separate, so using a single schema with a tenant identifier column isn't a preferred option. And as some tables will be exposed I'd prefer to keep power over the table names and not go to general tables and general fields where the data might be conceptually different between tenants. However, I am open to using different databases if it addresses the problems I encounter. It is also worth noting that in the future the amount of tenants will grow, the shared and unique tables will too. I know there are packages like django-tenant-schemas however they don't seem to fit my use case, as they focus on sharing a public schema with tenant schemas.

Initially, I attempted to structure the project using different Django apps: a common app for shared models across all schemas and additional apps for each tenant (e.g., App A for Tenant A) (it's a bit of an unconventional way of using apps). I implemented a custom migration command to set different schemas before migration. This way I can migrate all the apps in the 'common' app to all tenant schemas and afterwards I migrate the tenant specific apps. A stripped down version of this command:

```py
class Command(MigrationCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):  
        tenant_apps: list[str] = ["A", "B"]

        for tenant in tenant_apps:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute(sql=f"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {tenant}")

            with schema_context(schema=tenant):
                options["app_label"] = "common"
                options["database"] = tenant
                super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)

                if tenant != "common":
                    options["app_label"] = tenant
                    super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)
```

However, this approach failed, I encountered errors when attempting cascade deletions. For example, when I perform a cascade deletion in table_1 inside tenant_A and another tenant (tenant_B) has a unique table linked to this table_1 in its app then Django throws an error indicating this unique table doesn't exist for tenant_A. Which is true, it does not exist in the schema A as it is a table unique to schema B. This shows me that internally Django does expect the table to be there even though it is not, and is never created in the actual database. Which makes sense as django is not schema aware by itself.

My current approach involves removing the common app and turning all shared models into abstract models in a shared file. Each tenant-specific app imports from these abstract models and redefines the name of these tables. Additionally these tenant apps also define unique tables for that tenant. I've created a database router that selects different schemas in the same database based on the connection. A stripped down version of the code:

common/shared models:

```py
class Table1Base(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birth_date = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        db_table = "table_1"
```

tenant A app models.py:

```py
from common_models import Table1Base

class Table1(Table1Base):
    class Meta:
        db_table = f"A_{Table1Base._meta.db_table}"

class TableUnique(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    crew = models.ForeignKey(Table1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "A_unique_table_of_tenant"
```

tenant B app models.py:

```py
class Table1(Table1Base):
    class Meta:
        db_table = f"B_{Table1Base._meta.db_table}"
```

settings.py

```py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["myproject.schema_routers.SchemaRouter"]

DATABASES = {
    "default": {},
    "A": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        ...
        "OPTIONS": {"options": "-c search_path=A"},
    },
    "B": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        ...
        "OPTIONS": {"options": "-c search_path=B"},
    },
}
```

schema_routers.py

```py
class SchemaRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return self._get_schema_for_model(model)

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return self._get_schema_for_model(model)

    def _get_schema_for_model(self, model):
        current_schema = schema_context.get_current_schema()
        if current_schema:
            return current_schema
```

context_manager.py:

```py
thread_local = threading.local()

class schema_context:
    def __init__(self, schema):
        self.schema = schema

    def __enter__(self):
        thread_local.current_schema = self.schema

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        thread_local.current_schema = None

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_schema():
        return getattr(thread_local, "current_schema", None)
```

My data insertion and deletion commands are managed by dynamically importing the correct models from the corresponding app and then setting the correct router by doing `with schema_context(schema=tenant):`. This method seems to work but I am unsure about its long-term viability. And I'm unsure if this will cause problems in the future.

As I am no Django expert my question is: Is my current approach sustainable for the long run? If not, what changes should I make? Can I continue using Django, or should I consider another framework?
Thank you for the insights.